# How to take $n$ common out of $f(nx,ny)=ny+\sqrt{1+nx}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $f(x,y)=y+\sqrt{1+x}$ (where $x\geq 0,y\geq 0$)

To find if $f$ has increasing, decreasing or constant 
[returns to scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Returns_to_scale), I need to check the behaviour of $f(nx,ny)=ny+\sqrt{1+nx}$. (where $n>1$)

I need help to take $n$ out. My algebra skills are not good. Any hints ?

I thought about using natural log, but I don't see how I can open $\ln(1+nx)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$nf(x,y)=ny+n\sqrt{1+x}$
$nf(x,y)-f(nx,ny)=ny+n\sqrt{1+x}-ny-\sqrt{1+nx}=n\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+nx}$
$(n\sqrt{1+x})^2-(\sqrt{1+nx})^2=n^2+n^2x-1-nx=(n^2-1)+nx(n-1)$
$=(n-1)(n+1+nx)=(n-1)(n(x+1)+1)>0\:for\:n>1$
i.e. $n\sqrt{1+x}>\sqrt{1+nx}$ for $n>1$
i.e. $nf(x,y)>f(nx,ny)$ for $n>1$
Answer: decreasing returns to scale

Comment: Thanks .. but I have a query .. Why do we take $(n\sqrt{1+x})^2-(\sqrt{1+nx})^2$

Comment: You're welcome :D. To remove the sqrt sign. As $x^2$ is increasing in R+, comparing their square is the same as comparing them directly.

Comment: You're assuming that $x>0$ to arrive at your conclusion.  You need to break the problem into 2 separate intervals, $n\ge -\frac{n+1}{n}$ and $n< -\frac{n+1}{n}$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $x\geq 0,y\geq 0$ here .. my bad

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you for reminding. Edited. But referring to the wiki, we should only check for n>1.